# Create Excel File with multiple work sheets from JavaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

We have a Servlet that does a back-end DB query and displays results in a web page using HTML table. The number of columns and data is dynamic depending on user requests and it all works fine. Now we need to add a button to export this table data into excel.

This i think can be achieved straight-forward using approaches like below:

http://wsnippets.com/export-html-table-data-excel-sheet-using-jquery/
or

http://www.hybridplanet.co.in/tutorial/javascript/how-to-create-csv-or-excel-file-from-json-via-javascript

But the requirement is in addition to exporting results, we also need to add another work-sheet in the excel that gives some information about the query used.

1. Is it possible to create excel work-sheets and use them from JavaScript/Jquery? Something like the functionality available in apache poi api?
2. Or should i follow some other approach instead of javascript/jquery? We don't want to go back to the server and make another DB call.

Please advise and thanks for the help.

Comment: You can POST the information from the page back to the server and create the Excel file there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the table can be huge with 1000 rows of data and each row having around a max of 15 columns. Is it ok to 'post' this data back to the server?

Comment: Presumably you already sent it to the browser from the server? There should be no issue with sending it back.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to open an excel file template with the additional work-sheets already in it.